# Amazon product advertising API WCF4 Example

Tags: c#, api, wcf, soap, amazon-advertising-api

I try to get the Amazon PAAPI C# [Example](http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/3941) to run but my `ItemSearchResponse` is always null.

What i did:

1. set my `accessKeyId` and `secretKey` in `app.config`. (VS2012 gives a warning by the way that behavior has a invalid child element signingBehavior?!)
2. set `<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ImageSets">` in the AWSECommerceService.wsdl
3. run custom tool on `Reverence.svcmap`
4. corrected the namespaces in the Reference.cs
5. in program.cs: `itemSearch.AssociateTag = "myassociateTag-20";`

what am i doing wrong?
In Fiddler it seems that i am getting the right response to my request. At least i am getting search results in an xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the wsdl in the example seems to be not correct.

i replaced it with the one from

http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl

via copy and paste and did step 2,3 and 4 again. Now it works

Answer (score 0):

"run custom tool" is not available under visual studio 2012. Therefore I can get it working only under VS2010.